# Difficulty in understanding a number theory problem

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

So here's the problem:-

Find four distinct positive integers whose product is divisible by the sum of every pair of them.

I am having difficulty understanding what this means, as it can be interpreted 2 ways-

1. Find positive integers a,b,c,d such that ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd divides a abcdii
2. Find positive integers a,b,c,d such that:-

a+b divides abcd

a+c divides abcd

a+d divides abcd

b+c divides abcd

b+d divides abcd

c+d divides abcd

Which way is correct?

Comment: I think number 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definitely means interpretation (2) (except that you have left out the pair $a+d$).  To get interpretation (1), it would need to instead say "the sum of the *products* of every pair of them".  As written, it never mentions anything about multiplying the numbers in the pairs.